# HTTP/2 Request with JMeter fails with "nullSession" (jetty-alpn)

Tags: jmeter, jetty, http2, blazemeter, alpn

I've installed the [Blazemeter HTTP/2 Plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin) for JMeter and have trouble getting HTTP/2 requests to work.

### My minimal test looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

- Thread Group

  - HTTP2 Request

    - Server: stackoverflow.com
    - Protocol: https
  - View Result Tree Http2

#### Running the test shows the following sampler result in the view result tree:

```
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:1970-01-01 01:00:00 CET
Load time:0
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:2700
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:2700
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: nullSession


HTTP2SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

#### And the log:

```
2020-07-03 12:58:13,457 WARN o.a.j.v.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Error loading result renderer: org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderInBrowser
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.createComboRender(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:396) ~[jmeter-bzm-http2-1.5.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.createLeftPanel(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:322) ~[jmeter-bzm-http2-1.5.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.init(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:283) ~[jmeter-bzm-http2-1.5.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.<init>(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:118) ~[jmeter-bzm-http2-1.5.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGuiFromCache(GuiPackage.java:405) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.createTestElement(GuiPackage.java:352) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AddToTree.doAction(AddToTree.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) [?:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    ... 29 more
2020-07-03 12:58:19,743 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-07-03 12:58:19,745 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-07-03 12:58:19,751 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2020-07-03 12:58:20,368 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2020-07-03 12:58:20,371 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2020-07-03 12:58:20,372 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2020-07-03 12:58:20,373 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2020-07-03 12:58:20,376 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2020-07-03 12:58:20,376 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-07-03 12:58:20,381 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2020-07-03 12:58:20,489 WARN o.e.j.i.SelectorManager: Exception while notifying connection SslConnection@694fa68a::SocketChannelEndPoint@65c6505a{stackoverflow.com/151.101.129.69:443<->/192.168.0.178:34818,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=2/30000}{io=1/1,kio=-1,kro=-1}->SslConnection@694fa68a{NEED_UNWRAP,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@58ec6f77{stackoverflow.com/151.101.129.69:443<->/192.168.0.178:34818,CLOSED,fill=-,flush=-,to=10/30000}=>ALPNClientConnection@1d8fc708
org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: nullSession
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.NegotiatingClientConnection.onOpen(NegotiatingClientConnection.java:72) ~[jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onOpen(SslConnection.java:360) ~[jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.connectionOpened(SelectorManager.java:324) [jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:276) [jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1800(ManagedSelector.java:62) [jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:933) [jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806) [jetty-util-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938) [jetty-util-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: nullSession
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.handshakeFailed(SslConnection.java:933) ~[jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.flush(SslConnection.java:1142) ~[jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.NegotiatingClientConnection.onOpen(NegotiatingClientConnection.java:63) ~[jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: nullSession
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.getKickstartMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:1350) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Handshaker.java:1117) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:736) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1232) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1185) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.wrap(SslConnection.java:412) ~[jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.flush(SslConnection.java:1052) ~[jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.NegotiatingClientConnection.onOpen(NegotiatingClientConnection.java:63) ~[jetty-io-9.4.26.v20200117.jar:9.4.26.v20200117]
    ... 8 more
2020-07-03 12:58:20,494 WARN o.e.j.i.ManagedSelector: org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: nullSession
2020-07-03 12:58:20,498 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2020-07-03 12:58:20,498 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2020-07-03 12:58:20,499 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-07-03 12:58:20,500 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

### Changing protocol to HTTP

If I change the protocol to **HTTP**, I get the following sampler result instead:

```
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2020-07-03 13:11:59 CEST
Load time:0
Connect Time:354
Latency:0
Size in bytes:1072
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:1072
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Response message:null
```

And this is the log:

```
2020-07-03 13:11:58,817 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-07-03 13:11:58,819 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-07-03 13:11:58,824 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2020-07-03 13:11:59,307 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2020-07-03 13:11:59,307 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2020-07-03 13:11:59,307 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2020-07-03 13:11:59,308 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2020-07-03 13:11:59,309 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2020-07-03 13:11:59,310 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-07-03 13:11:59,312 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2020-07-03 13:11:59,690 INFO c.b.j.h.s.HTTP2StreamHandler: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2020-07-03 13:11:59,691 INFO c.b.j.h.s.HTTP2StreamHandler: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2020-07-03 13:11:59,692 INFO c.b.j.h.s.HTTP2StreamHandler: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2020-07-03 13:11:59,692 INFO c.b.j.h.s.HTTP2StreamHandler: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2020-07-03 13:11:59,693 INFO c.b.j.h.s.HTTP2StreamHandler: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2020-07-03 13:11:59,693 INFO c.b.j.h.s.HTTP2StreamHandler: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2020-07-03 13:11:59,736 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2020-07-03 13:11:59,737 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2020-07-03 13:12:19,741 ERROR c.b.j.h.s.HTTP2SampleResult: Error while await for response
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1784) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.awaitResponses(HTTP2Connection.java:171) ~[jmeter-bzm-http2-1.5.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.lambda$waitAllResponses$1(HTTP2Request.java:587) ~[jmeter-bzm-http2-1.5.jar:?]
    at java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:981) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.waitAllResponses(HTTP2Request.java:585) [jmeter-bzm-http2-1.5.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.threadFinished(HTTP2Request.java:548) [jmeter-bzm-http2-1.5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:774) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) [jorphan.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) [jorphan.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadFinished(JMeterThread.java:741) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:329) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
2020-07-03 13:12:19,756 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-07-03 13:12:19,758 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

#### My Setup:

I am using JMeter 5.2.1 with OpenJDK 8 (`openjdk version "1.8.0_252"`) on Linux (`version 5.6.15-arch1-1`)

(*Got the same results with JMeter 5.3 on Ubuntu 20.04, running in CLI mode*)

I added the following line at the top of my `jmeter` startup script, as per requirement of the HTTP/2 plugin:

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/jmeter/lib/alpn-boot-8.1.13.v20181017.jar"
```

How can I solve or debug this issue?

#### Update:

I found out that as soon as I use `alpn-boot` as mentioned above, I have the same behavior for regular HTTP requests, so it seems to be a problem from that library. There is a mapping table for jetty-alpn versions against Java versions at https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-alpn/blob/master/docs/version_mapping.properties and it currently does not contain my Java version.

The [docs](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-alpn#openjdk-8-version-to-alpn-version-mapping) say

> The table only shows the mapping up to OpenJDK 8u242, the last version that required the ALPN boot jar.

But if I start JMeter without the alpn argument, I see results like this (HTTP/2 with HTTPS):

```
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
```

Comment: I think I found the issue: "You need Jetty 9.4.28 to work with 8u252." https://webtide.com/jetty-alpn-java-8u252/ - will post as answer when I was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out, the combination of OpenJDK 8u252 and Jetty 9.4.26 (shipped with JMeter) is not compatible.

The ALPN APIs have been backported to Java 8u252 and Jetty 9.4.28, and `alpn-boot` is not needed anymore.

More information: https://webtide.com/jetty-alpn-java-8u252/

Updating the Jetty libraries to 9.4.28 helped:

- Download files from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.4.28.v20200408/ and https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-client/9.4.28.v20200408/
- Replace `jetty*-9.4.26*` files in `jmeter/lib` by their 9.4.28 counterparts from the downloaded archive

**Update: List of files**

```
lib/jetty-alpn-client-9.4.28.v20200408.jar
lib/jetty-alpn-openjdk8-client-9.4.28.v20200408.jar
lib/jetty-client-9.4.28.v20200408.jar
lib/jetty-http-9.4.28.v20200408.jar
lib/jetty-io-9.4.28.v20200408.jar
lib/jetty-util-9.4.28.v20200408.jar
```

Comment: There are no jetty-alpn-*client* jars in jetty 9.4.28+. What did you do with them ? Removed ? Or kept ? In both cases it still fails for me ALPN related issues. JDK 1.8.0_265, JMeter 5.3.0, JMeter HTTP2 plugin 1, Jetty 9.4.31.

Comment: @martin-g I updated the answer with a list of files and a second download link. I remember that I downloaded it from a different location first and then found the rest of the files in `jetty-distribution`...

Comment: Thank you, Fabian! The ALPN client jars (jetty-alpn-client-9.4.31.v20200723.jar and jetty-alpn-openjdk8-client-9.4.31.v20200723.jar) were not part of jetty-distribution and I thought they were no more released. I've downloaded them from Maven Central and now everything is OK!