# Request Timeout - JMeter HTTP2 Plugin

Tags: java, jmeter, jetty, http2, blazemeter

I'm using the HTTP2 Sampler by Blazemeter, which officially provided by JMeter Plugin Manager.

At their repo, there are some steps to be made: https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin

I applied everyone of that required steps on my mac (I also paid attention to the Mac-specific details).
After successfully integrating it, I tried to make a HTTP2 Call to my local HTTP2 REST Service.
After trying that, it stays on the loop and nothing happens. No error, no warning, just the timeout error after I stop the request.

Here is my sampler result:

```
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2020-07-30 20:03:53 CEST
Load time:0
Connect Time:110
Latency:0
Size in bytes:928
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:928
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Response message:null


HTTP2SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: ISO-8859-1
```

Here is the response after stopping the request:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1957)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2092)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.awaitResponses(HTTP2Connection.java:171)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:221)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:145)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:121)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

I tried nearly everything out and also got to this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62714281/http-2-request-with-jmeter-fails-with-nullsession-jetty-alpn) regarding to jetty incompatibilities of the newer version.

HTTP1 requests still work, but the HTTP2 requests are reaching the server, but never handle anything.
I tested also some public HTTP2 sites which also couldn't be reached by JMeter. In addition to that, a simple HTTP2 Request via Curl worked. So there is no problem with my server.
There is definently something wrong with the HTTP2 JMeter plugin and I have no idea why.

Pls hlp ._.

Comment: can you provide a reproducer in github and don't forget to put your jmeter test scenario there too, I like to run the test in my local :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase HEAP size to not less than 5Gb and set-up time-out in HTTP2 Request Manager. After all above were done, my exception was gone.